# Problem while using Custom Tabs

Tags: module, magento-1

I am using Custom Tab code **"\Phpcmsframework\Customtabs"**. Followed link is [Custom Tabs](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/).
**Expected Result** : It shows Custom Tab only while adding product details. Here in image Pickup/Dispatch Address show only on this page.
[image]
**Current Result** : It showing Custom Tab in Previous section ie. Product Type section.Showing Pickup/Dispatch Address Tab in both pages.

[image]

Here is my Customtabs.xml file.Please refer it.
customtabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_tab</name>
            <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_tab</name>
            <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
</layout>
```

Comment: YKJ this Fighpig blog is properly work.it may be your some mistake in code

Comment: show relevant codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove Code from Customtabs.Xml

`<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_tab</name>
            <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>`

Override Block Tabs.php Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
added code

```
$urlparm = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set', null);
    if(isset($urlparm)){
     $this->addTab('customtab', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('My Custom Tab'),
                'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab')->toHtml()),
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_tab</name>
            <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
```

from customtabs.xml

`adminhtml_catalog_product_new` layout has been `used for 1st step of product` that means when `we have selecting a product type during product creation`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually right now it doesn't showing tabs from both pages. I want this tab on second page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your custom tab class `extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` and `implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`.
If it doesn't it should.

Then you are obligated to implement the method  `canShowTab`.
Here you can put your code to determine if the tab should be shown.
Something like this:

```
public function canShowTab() {
    //get the current product instance
    $product = Mage::registry('product');
    //if on edit mode show the tab
    if ($product->getId()){
        return true;
    }
    //if on add mode and the attribute set has not been selected yet don't show the tab
    if (!$product->getAttributeSetId()){
        return false;
    }
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    //if creating a configurable product and you have selected the configurable attributes, show the tab
    if ($request->getParam('type') == 'configurable'){
        if ($request->getParam('attributes')){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```